# How run CLOUD FUNCTION on old files in the bucket (trigger: cloud storage (create/finalise))

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function :

```
What does it do: uploads csv file into bigquery
Trigger: cloud storage (create/finalize)
GCS bucket status: already has 100s of files
regularly more files are uploaded to the bucket daily
```

I tested my function and looks perfect, whenever I upload new file, it goes into bigquery straight away.

QUESTION:
How can I upload the files which already been in the bucket before I deploy the function?

Comment: Easiest solution which comes to my mind is: copying all files to a temp bucket and move them back to the bucket, however seems a bit silly but old files will trigger the function and get uploaded into bigquery.

Comment: Same, to generate the events is to recreate the files. Write them again (finalize)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting as community wiki to help other community members that will encounter this issue. As stated by @Sana and @guillaume blaquiere:

The easiest solution is copying all files to a temp bucket and moving them back to the bucket, however it seems a bit silly but old files will trigger the function and get uploaded into BigQuery. Generating the events is to recreate the files and write them again to finalize.